# Do log messages have an impact on performance?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

I have a big `appengine-java` application that uses `java.util.Logging`.

For debugging purposes, I put an INFO message basically on every put, delete, get or query. The application-wide logging settings filters all log messages with level lower than WARNING.

My question is: **all this INFO messages, even though filtered, do slow down my app or not?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every additional operation you perform will add to the overhead you have. I have had some REST calls time out because I had forgotten a logger in the wrong place :)

So yes, they do slow things down, but to what effect is very, very highly dependent on how much you are logging. In a normal situation, logging should not have any noticeable performance penalty. This should be easy to measure, just set your logging level higher to not log so much, and see if the application performs faster!